# Order by Price Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Just wondering how I can get to order products in Expresso Store by Price (High to Low and Low to High) using a drop down.

I've got sort working by using Dynamic Parameters but can't work out how to do this with Price?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me with a little more thought I just need to orderby "price" and then use sort "asc or desc"

Using Mo Variables to select the correct option from my drop down.

```
<form method="post" action="{path='shop/category/{segment_3}{if current_query_string}?{current_query_string}{/if}'}">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{csrf_token}" />
                    <select name="sort">
                      <option {if post:sort == "desc"} selected="selected"{/if} name="sort" value="desc">Descending</option>
                      <option {if post:sort == "asc"} selected="selected"{/if} name="sort" value="asc">Ascending</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="orderby">
                        <option {if post:orderby == "price"} selected="selected"{/if} name="orderby" value="price">Price</option>
                        <option {if post:orderby == "title"} selected="selected"{/if} name="orderby" value="title">Name</option>
                   </select>
               </div>
        <div class="small-2 columns">
        <input role="button" aria-label="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="button postfix submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```